# Drupal custom tabular View

Tags: views

Use Case: I have two differnent Content Types, A and B, each with a taxonomy fields 'State'.

Content Type A has two nodes, with `California` and `South Dakota` selected.

Content Type B has two nodes, with `Alabama` selected in both nodes.

The requirement is to created a tabular View that would look like this:

[image]

So within the Views interface, how do I create this?

http://filedb.experts-exchange.com/incoming/2015/04_w17/909525/view.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I think the [Views Aggregator Plus](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator) module can be of help. Among others it has possibilities to tally and enumerate views fields, so I think you can make the summary table you're asking for.

The module description is as follows:

> In addition to what Views and Views Calc do, this module:
>
> - enumerates group members
> - produces tallies, i.e. textual histograms
> - aggregates on Views PHP code-snippet evalutations
> - can filter out result rows on regexp patterns
> - gives you sorting on Views' Math expressions
> - can process Webform submissions
> - lets you add your own custom aggregation functions
>
> ... and it puts summary statistics at the bottom of your aggregated
>   table as well!